# Crystal Report - YTD formula

Tags: crystal-reports

I am creating a crystal report on Crystal 2016 and would like to show the YTD figure on the report. The start of the year is 01/04/2021 and end of the year is 31/03/2022. But this should change depending on the To Date parameter e.g if To Date is within 01/04/2021 - 31/03/2022 then the date should go back to 01/04/2021 but if the date is 01/05/2022 then the start of the year should be 01/04/2022.

I have two date parameters - From Date and To Date where the user selects any date and shows them the data for that period.

Is there a formula I can create which shows the YTD amount (net amount) from the To Date parameter. E.g 01/04/2021 - 22/02/2022 (To Date). If this falls in the new year then the formula should pick up the new year e.g 01/04/2022 - 01/05/2022.

Comment: Have you looked into using Running Total Fields?  You can set the Running Total Field so that it only evaluates records that are between the start and end date for your fiscal year.  You can find some great examples online to help you get started, and if you get stuck, come back and update this question or ask a new question to get more specific help with your Running Total Fields and the formulas needed to make them work.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to automatically show the ytd total from my date parameters? The date parameters can be any date value. If the user puts in dates 01/10/2021 - 01/02/2022, then the YTD should automatically calculate the total from 01/04/2021 - 01/02/2022?

Comment: Yes, that can be done using a Summary Field or a Running Total Field.  The date parameters are used in record selection so that only records within the date range appear on the report.  A Summary Field would summarize all of the data in the report easily.  You only need Running Total Fields if there are records in the report you do not want to include in the summarization of the data.

Comment: I have used this formula to give me the financial year -
IF Month ( {?To Date} ) <= 4
THEN ToText( Year ( {?To Date} ) - 1, 0, "" ) + '/' + ToText( Year ( {?To Date} ), 0, "" )
ELSE ToText( Year ( {?To Date} ), 0, "" ) + '/' + ToText( Year ( {?To Date} ) + 1, 0, "" )

How can i show the total net amount for this FY period e.g 2021/2022 £1500